# InitiateSystemShutdown fails. Error code 53

Tags: c#, system-shutdown

I'm trying to remotely reboot/shutdown a computer.
I tried using the InitiateSystemShutdown function from AdvAPI32.dll but it returned false. `GetLastError()` shows the error code 53 (`ERROR_BAD_NETPATH`). 
It seems like I have problem with the way I supply the computer name:

```
InitiateSystemShutdown("http://192.168.10.11:16992", "", 60, true, true);
```

I called the `AdjustTokenPrivilege` method first, in order to set `SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` privilage, it succeeded but it didn't help.

Comment: I wouldn't think that the path to the remote machine should contain the http protocol specifier or portnumber... Try this instead: InitiateSystemShutdown("\\192.168.10.11", "", 60, true, true);

Comment: Take a look here for an example: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.initiatesystemshutdown

Comment: We could have some fun rebooting web servers if that would work.  It doesn't, you must supply a machine name, not an IP address.  And of course your user account must have admin rights on that machine.

Comment: now when i think about it, it really makes sence that it fails... why should i be able to rebbot a web service? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be the name of the computer, not some arbitrary http address. To get the name you pass bring up a command prompt and type `set`. There should be a variable called `ComputerName`. Try passing that in, instead.